# How to pass system properties to the tests in gradle in the smart way?

Tags: gradle, system-properties

**build.gradle**

```
tasks.withType(Test){
    systemProperties=System.properties
    println systemProperties['param']
}
```

Now I can either pass parameters in the command line:

```
gradle test -Dparam=10
```

or put them in **gradle.properties**:

```
systemProp.param=15
```

Ideally I would like to put the defaults in the **gradle.properties**, and be able to overwrite them from the command line. Unfortunately if I do that, the gradle.properties has precedence, and `-Dparam=10` is ignored.

Could you offer any solutions on that?

Comment: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/can-props-from-gradle-properties-be-overwritten-with-d-parameter/6759/6 It seems like system properties defined in gradle.properties currently cannot be overwritten by using -D

Comment: thank you, updating gradle wrapper to the newest, solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2122

It works since 2.12 or 2.13 "the smart way" already!

The example above is working, the command line -D option overdrives the defaults in **gradle.properties**

Answer (score 0):

I am using gradle 2.12 and sharing how I used it:

```
test {
  // support passing -Dsystem.property=value to bootRun task
  systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

I have JUnit tests that I wanted to skip unless a property was used to include such tests. Using JUnit Assume for including the tests conditionally:

```
//first line of test
assumeThat(Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("deep.test.run","false"),true)
```

Doing this with gradle required that the system property provided at the time of running gradle build, shown here,

```
gradle build -Ddeep.test.run=true
```

was indeed passed through to the tests.

Hope this helps others trying out this approach for running tests conditionally.